# What are promising battery technologies for longer battery life?

Tags: solid-state-devices

Most electrical devices  lack the capacity to work for longer time (e.g. smart phones work only for a day) without recharging. This is mostly as a result of low energy storage capacity in current chemical cells. I am not an expert in solid state physics nor am I an expert in battery technology.  I am just curiosity driven simple guy in the corner who wants to know why  we could not have small size batteries that last longer than aday in smart phones, more than a week in PC's and months in electric cars.  So,  my question is, what is the current status of battery technology? What options do we have in parallel with chemical solid state batteries?

Comment: you could have a cell phone that runs for a month it'd be the size of a brick.  in the 1980s, a cell phone that size would only run for 1 day.

Comment: @Jasen That's mostly because it drew orders of magnitude more power.

Comment: somo of it is, but Li-po is also way better than Ni-Cd,

Comment: *"What is the current status of battry technology ?"* Geez, you could have looked that one up easily. Comparing memory devices (you mean semiconductor technology) advances to battery technology als shows that you have very little insight in this topic. Maybe you should do some research into battery technology first and then possibly **you** could come up with a breakthrough idea. That seems to me much better than just complaining about it.

Comment: Go study physics & invent a better battery technology for us ...

Comment: The question is just to know what is happenning in battery research and not to disappoint you in any way.  The answer  Robheric gave below is outstanding!

Comment: Please do edit the question a bit after reading the page I linked to you in the other comment. It'll make good practice, maybe get rid of some of those '-' votes on your question (the people who cast them aren't allowed to "take them off" by the site until it's been edited), and may draw some mkre attention and interesting responses/answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the need to permanently contain both the reactants and the reaction products (except for the special-case "zinc-air batteries"), batteries cannot be more that a certain amount efficient in terms of mass, or volume, power density.

Because of this fact, researchers have been working hard for many years on portable (micro) power generation ideas, and alternative energy storage devices.

One alternative storage device recently developed/released is the "EDL Capacitor"/"Supercapacitor" with an order of magnitude higher power density than any previous capacitors.

A new (small) generation device that has come from this pursuit is the Hydrogen Fuel Cell, along with the closely related NiMH battery technology, and hydrocarbon fuel cells.

Finally, there are several "over the horizon" technologies still being developed/pursued, the most promising (imo) of these is the pairing of a new generation of super-small [microturbines](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/peewee-power-66208176/) with similarly miniscule [microgenerators.](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2004/11/041124154548.htm)

Comment: @GemechuFanta thank you, please click the "accepted" (checkmark in a circle) link next to the answer if you feel that it sufficiently answers your question. Also, please have a quick read through http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour to get a better feel for how this site works best. :)